# What is the difference between generics

Tags: java

Ok, i read this question in this web-site and it did not answer me the main point.

Assume we have like this:

```
public <T extends Number> void someMethod(List<T> list)
```

AND

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends Number> list)
```

Consider that I **do not need any lower bound or upper list bound**. So rejection of these things, what is the difference between it **in this situation**? Because ? is List of unknown and T is List of T, but from one side they are similar in this situation (methods above).

(P.s. I know differences between it, but in this situation it looks for me very similar and as I consider it does not matter what to use.)

Comment: You can't add elements to `List<? extends Number>`.

Comment: yes, this is true, now I see. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
public <T extends Number> void someMethod(List<T> list)
```

You can make use of the unknown type T, in your code. Eg:

```
T obj = list.get(0);
list.add(obj);
```

This is not possible here:

```
public void someMethod(List<? extends Number> list)
```

Comment: in wildcard I can use a subtype of number, the same is in my generic type or not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Ernusc with the first declaration you can use `T` as a type within your method signature, rather than having to use `Number` (and giving you an easier time to change it in the future if you needed)

Answer (score 1):

List `<? extends Number>` means anything that extends Number here.
So assume you have classes like

```
public class  Example<T extends Number> {

public <T extends Number> void someMethod(List<T> list) ...

public <T extends Number> void someOtherMethod(List<T> list) ...

}

public class SomeClass extends Number {
}

public class SomeClass2 extends Number {
}
```

and you created an instance  like

```
Example<SomeClass> myExample =  new Example<SomeClass>();
```

so when you want to use your methods here, the input parameters must be insances exactly of the same class SomeClass, we cant use SomeClass2 here. For example the following is invalid:

```
List<SomeClass2> someClass2 =  new ArrayList<SomeClass2>();
example.someMethod(someClass2);
```

but if you use `<? extends Number>` as an input parameter to the someMethod then it is possible. You can pass anything that extends Number, someClass2 or 3 , 4 or any other class.